# "Validating Application example..." when Running to device

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, macos, xcode6.1

I am on OS X Yosemite using Xcode 6.1.1 and on any project when I try to Run it to my device it tells me:

```
Validating Application example...
```

I have already tried to clear cache on my device and I have tried to reboot my computer. Possibly a fresh Xcode install might work? Not sure.

Has anyone experienced this or know how to fix this?

[image: screenshot showing the error]

Comment: Frome the image it is seems that Xcode don't finish Indexing. Waite until it completes, and try again.

Comment: It never finishes, It goes on forever

Comment: In my case reboot of device worked for me.

Comment: I tried that too.... Even with Xcode 6 beta 3, it does it :/

My device is jailbroke but idk anything that would cause this...

Comment: May reason is that your device jailbroken... Did you tried another device?

Comment: Did you get it fixed?